# AngularJS constants in main module

Tags: angularjs, constants, angular-resource

It looks like there's several ways to define constants in Angular.

In this example we are defining two constants in our main module *config.js*:

```
  'use strict';
  angular.module('app')
    .constant('URL', 'http://localhost:8080/users')
    .constant('RESOURCES', (function () {
                var resource = 'http://localhost:8080';
                return {
                  USERS: resource + '/users'
                }
              }));
  }());
```

We have a factory that uses these constants. 
In the first case, when we want to use the "simple" constant (URL), it works like a charm:

```
  var app = angular.module('app.user');
  app.factory('User', ['URL', '$resource', function (URL, $resource) {
    return $resource(URL + '/:id', null, {
                       get: {method: 'GET'}
                     });
  }]);
```

However, when we try to use the main RESOURCES constants, like this:

```
  var app = angular.module('app.user');
  app.factory('User', ['RESOURCES', '$resource', function (RESOURCES, $resource) {
    return $resource(RESOURCES.USERS + '/:id', null, {
                       get: {method: 'GET'}
                     });
  }]);
```

We get an *undefined* error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your constant is the function passed to module.constant(), not the value returned by the function.

Comment: It's worse than that it's a self-invoking function, it might just work by returning a function and calling it then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have an error with this code, look at the closing of the block

```
app.constant('RESOURCES', (function() {
    var resource = 'http://localhost:8080';
    return {
      USERS: resource + '/users'
    }
  })());
```

Comment: Thank you! It was that! Sorry for the stupid beginner question.

Comment: Np, just check the console next time ;)